# CPT and ACF Repeater not working together

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields

Here's the page template code I'm working with, defined into sections...

```
<?php

//* Template Name: Partnerships Archive

?>


<!-- Header =========================================== -->

<?php get_header(); ?>




<!-- Homepage Header Video =========================================== -->


<div class="subpage-video-sca">

  <!-- VIDEO -->
  <div class="subpage-desktop-vid-sca">
    <video title="<?php the_field('seo_video_title'); ?>" autoplay loop muted playsinline>
      <source src="<?php the_field('vimeo_link'); ?>" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
  </div>

  <!-- GRAD-OVERLAY -->

  <div class="subpage-overlay-image-sca">
  </div>

  <!-- OVERLAID TEXT -->
  <div class="subpage-text-over-video-sca">
    <div>
      <h1><?php the_field('sub_page_title'); ?></h1>
      <p><?php the_field('paragraph'); ?></p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>





<!-- Breadcrumbs =========================================== -->

<?php echo do_shortcode("[breadcrumbs]"); ?>










<!-- Main Content =========================================== -->

<div class="wrap">
      <?php
        $args = array( 
          'post_type' => 'partnerships',
          'orderby' => 'title',
          'order' => 'ASC'
        );
        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

      ?>

      <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

        <a class="one-third partnership-block" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">

            <img src="<?php the_field('logo'); ?>" alt="<?php the_title();?> graphic">

        </a>

      <?php $products_count = $the_query->current_post + 1; ?>
      <?php if ( $products_count % 4 == 0): ?>

      </div><div class="row">

      <?php endif; ?>


      <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
</div>






<!-- Testimonials =========================================== -->

<div class="wrap">
  <div class="page-section-headers pt-testimonials-container txt-right">
    <h1>WHAT <span class="red">OUR PARTNERS</span><br>HAVE TO SAY</h1>
  </div>




  <?php if( have_rows('testimonial') ): ?>

    <div class="testimonial-slider-container slick-slider">

    <?php while( have_rows('testimonial') ): the_row(); 

      // vars
      $text = get_sub_field('testimonial_text');
      $client = get_sub_field('client_name');
      $company = get_sub_field('client_company');

      ?>

      <div class="testimonial-slider-single">

        <p><?php echo $text; ?></p>
        <h2><?php echo $client; ?></h2>
        <h3><?php echo $company; ?><h3>

      </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

    </div>

  <?php endif; ?>


</div>
```

**The code in the main content area** is pulling through custom post types I have.

**The code in the Testimonials area** is pulling through data from an ACF Repeater field for this page specifically.

They both work independently but when I have them both on the page at the same time, the testimonials doesn't pull through.

That said, Ive just noticed that when I put the testimonials first and the main content after, they both work!!

Can anyone help? Is there something I haven't closed properly in the Main content or something? I don't get it...

It's wordpress, using Genesis Framework, latest versions of both. The page is here: http://staging.seedcreativeacademy.co.uk/partnerships/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add  wp_reset_postdata(),after while :

```
<div class="wrap">
      <?php
        $args = array( 
          'post_type' => 'partnerships',
          'orderby' => 'title',
          'order' => 'ASC'
        );
        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

      ?>

      <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

        <a class="one-third partnership-block" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">

            <img src="<?php the_field('logo'); ?>" alt="<?php the_title();?> graphic">

        </a>

      <?php $products_count = $the_query->current_post + 1; ?>
      <?php if ( $products_count % 4 == 0): ?>

      </div><div class="row">

      <?php endif; ?>


      <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much - works perfectly! I guess if including multiple elements I need to reset the post data!